# Android Studio 3.2 Canary 12/14/15/16 has no Github integration

Tags: android-studio, github, android-studio-3.2, github-integration

The Android Studio 3.2 Canary version 12/14/15/16 doesn't have github integration, so I can't clone it from it, and  when I try to pull/push on an already cloned repository, it keeps me asking for credentials everytime, and after 3 times trying to logging in, it gives me an unauthorized error. Already tried with ssh, and my credentials are correct when I check them at Settings > Version Control > Github
I use github integration heavily on daily basis, which makes me stuck with canary 8 version.
This shows the start screen of both versions:
[image]

Comment: Github is just a hosting service for git. Perhaps they moved it under Git

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu I tried git but didnt work as well